# How to open mgconsole when running Memgraph Platform?

Tags: memgraphdb

I run Memgraph using `docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform`. Yesterday I updated it to the latest docker image using docker pull `memgraph/memgraph-platform`.

Now when I run the command to run the docker I get log output in my terminal, but I don't see `mgconsole`. How can I start it?

This is the part of the output that I get:

```
2023-08-25 06:14:41,015 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/programs/lab.conf" during parsing
2023-08-25 06:14:41,015 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/programs/memgraph.conf" during parsing
2023-08-25 06:14:41,015 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded
2023-08-25 06:14:41,016 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2023-08-25 06:14:42,019 INFO spawned: 'memgraph' with pid 7
2023-08-25 06:14:42,021 INFO spawned: 'lab' with pid 8
You are running Memgraph v2.10.1
To get started with Memgraph, visit https://memgr.ph/start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run `mgconsole` that is part of your Docker image do one of the following:

- get the running-container-id with `docker ps` and then run

  `docker exec -ti <running-container-id> mgconsole`
- run `docker run -ti --entrypoint=mgconsole memgraph/memgraph-platform`

If you are connecting to local Memgraph with `mgconsole` on Windows and Mac, make sure to provide the argument `--host host.docker.internal`:

```
docker run -ti --entrypoint=mgconsole memgraph/memgraph-platform --host host.docker.internal
```